# Parse information from JSON with EJS

Tags: json, node.js, express, ejs

How do I access only certain parts of JSON response? Is this even possible?

I get the whole response to show up on my EJS template as:

```
{ "result": { "price": { "last": 2086.004, "high": 2228.857, "low": 1980, "change": { "percentage": -0.048247334, "absolute": -105.74609 } }, "volume": 11616.328 }, "allowance": { "cost": 4279664, "remaining": 3766767537 } }
```

With:

```
var rows =<%-JSON.stringify(data)%>
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = rows;
```

But how would I access, let’s say result.price.last?

I've tried all kind of approaches, but none seem to work.

Comment: You mean `rows.result.price.last`?

Comment: well, any of these values would do. I think i could then figure myself from there, but problem is, i cant get any one of the values to show up. i tried rows with different indexes and loops but nothing so far has worked.

Comment: like, do i have possibility do like rows.result.price.last? or do i have to like iterate everything with loop looking for words in array or something.

Comment: There are no arrays in your JSON, just objects...

Comment: yeah, anyways rows.result.price.last is also undefined. how do i access any of it.

Comment: What's wrong with just doing `<%= data.result.price.last %>`

Comment: I dont know, i could swear i tried it atleast 15 times last night... but now its working.. thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Andrew Li proposed, `rows.result.price.last`, I could swear I tried it at least twice, Oh well, it works now.